# Accessing Document inside Object using plain Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a sample HTML structure like below where there are two DOM available on the same HTML. I am trying to access the `<h1>` tag, using Javascript in the HTML which is embedded inside the `<object>` tag. I have tried using the following javascript and couldnt get the text value of the H1.Please note, I want to achieve this using plain javascript only not using jquery.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Test JS</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="parent">
    <h1 class="header_Child">I am inside parent html</h1>
<div class="objectWrapper">
    <object type="text/html"> 
        #document
        <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>
            <head>
                <title>I am an embedded HTML</title>
            </head>
            <body>
                <h1 class="header_Child">I am inside child html</h1>
            </body>
         <html>
     </object>
</div>
</div>
</body>
```

Javascript:

```
var obj = document.getElementsByTagName('object');
var header= obj[1].querySelectorAll('h1').innerHTML;
```

Comment: Why would you use `<object>` instead of `<iframe>`? It has more or less the same effect except that the way `iframes` are handled (especially around JS) is much better documented.

Comment: May be I will try in the future. But for this particular scenario I can't modify the object into iframe.